# Bluetooth Enable Disable ADB command and Opening Android Activity with Android Driver not working in Some Android 7 devices

Tags: java, automation, adb, appium

```
Result: Parcel(
  0x00000000: ffffffff 0000006e 0065004e 00640065 '....n...N.e.e.d.'
  0x00000010: 00420020 0055004c 00540045 004f004f ' .B.L.U.E.T.O.O.'
  0x00000020: 00480054 00410020 004d0044 004e0049 'T.H. .A.D.M.I.N.'
  0x00000030: 00700020 00720065 0069006d 00730073 ' .p.e.r.m.i.s.s.'
  0x00000040: 006f0069 003a006e 004e0020 00690065 'i.o.n.:. .N.e.i.'
  0x00000050: 00680074 00720065 00750020 00650073 't.h.e.r. .u.s.e.'
  0x00000060: 00200072 00300032 00300030 006e0020 'r. .2.0.0.0. .n.'
  0x00000070: 0072006f 00630020 00720075 00650072 'o.r. .c.u.r.r.e.'
  0x00000080: 0074006e 00700020 006f0072 00650063 'n.t. .p.r.o.c.e.'
  0x00000090: 00730073 00680020 00730061 00610020 's.s. .h.a.s. .a.'
  0x000000a0: 0064006e 006f0072 00640069 0070002e 'n.d.r.o.i.d...p.'
  0x000000b0: 00720065 0069006d 00730073 006f0069 'e.r.m.i.s.s.i.o.'
  0x000000c0: 002e006e 004c0042 00450055 004f0054 'n...B.L.U.E.T.O.'
  0x000000d0: 0054004f 005f0048 00440041 0049004d 'O.T.H._.A.D.M.I.'
  0x000000e0: 002e004e 00000000                   'N.......        ')
```

While running the following ADB Command, the above error thrown in CLI.

**Enable:**

> adb shell service call bluetooth_manager 6

**Disable:**

> adb shell service call bluetooth_manager 9

Also tried with the appium android driver activity, Nearly the same permission issue in Samsung Galaxy Note 8 (7.1.1), Samsung Galaxy Note 2 (7.0). But both activity and ADB command works fine in Samsung Galaxy S7 edge (7.0).

**Android driver activity error:**

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error occured while starting App. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command '/home/user/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 83f0374b42535532 shell am start -W -n com.android.settings/com.android.settings.bluetooth.BluetoothSettings -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000' exited with code 1'; Stderr: 'java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.settings/.bluetooth.BluetoothSettings launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } } from null (pid=24744, uid=2000) requires android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1693)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1646)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivityAndWait(ActivityManagerNative.java:3646)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.runStart(Am.java:658)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:392)
    at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:51)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:125)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:301)'; Code: '1' (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

Any solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: Any one know about this issue and solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

the problem that you had faced because that you run your command without root permission.

run this command if your phone is already rooted :

```
adb root
```

after :

```
adb shell service call bluetooth_manager 6
```